# How to check if something is drawn on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How do I check if there is data or something drawn on a canvas?

I have this `<canvas id="my-canvas"></canvas>` element, and I want to check if my canvas has something drawn on it.

Comment: Where you have your canvas? on page? on applet? on mobile?

Comment: I edited my post. Basically I just wanted to check the element on my HTML page if it has something drawn on it.

Comment: Is there a native drawing functionality in canvas that you need to monitor? How do people draw on the canvas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of checking every single pixel, it may be much more efficient to merely record every time the canvas gets filled or stroked.

Once a fill or stroke or has happened, then you know that something has been drawn.

Of course 'how' is very application specific, since we don't know how your canvas is getting drawn on in the first place.

Answer (score 34):

A good way I have found is to use the `toDataURL()` function and compare it with another, blank canvas. If they are different, than the one you are comparing it to has something on it. Something like this:

```
canvas = document.getElementById('editor');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){
    ctx.lineTo(e.pageX,e.pageY);
    ctx.stroke();
});

document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click',function(){
    if(canvas.toDataURL() == document.getElementById('blank').toDataURL())
        alert('It is blank');
    else
        alert('Save it!');
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amaan/rX572/)

I can't take credit for this, I just stumbled upon it and it fixed my same issue. Maybe this will help somebody at some point.

Comment: When i get the .toDataURL() of blank canvas then also it returns data url so i cannot compare the way you did.

Answer (score 9):

I haven't seen this kind of question in Stackoverflow till now.. but an interesting One to answer..

The only way(I guess) is to check through pixel by pixel, i.e., check the `R, G, B, A` of each pixel,
 if those values are equal to zero then we can say that the pixel is empty..
This is the technique I used to write the below code snippet.. just go through it

```
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas  = document.getElementById('canvas');
  if(!canvas.getContext) return;
  var ctx     = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var w       = canvas.width = canvas.height = 100;
  var drawn   = null;
  var d       = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, w); //image data 
  var len     = d.data.length;
  for(var i =0; i< len; i++) {
    if(!d.data[i]) {
      drawn = false;
    }else if(d.data[i]) {
      drawn = true;
      alert('Something drawn on Canvas');
      break;
    }
  }
  if(!drawn) {
    alert('Nothing drawn on canvas.. AKA, Canvas is Empty');
  }
}
```

### [Test it Here](http://jsbin.com/ofoto4)

Comment: Thanks for this looks logical but seems impractical (the code might work for some), I did tried this code, but it slows down the page considerably.  Often times i get Stop Script message from Firefox.  Maybe the issue is I got quite big canvas (575px x 500px)?

Comment: I found no problem when testing at (1280 X 580) http://jsbin.com/ofoto4/5 .Tested on Firefox 3.6.13

Comment: I might have some issues with other parts of my code. Anyway thanks for this. I'll still consider this and keep this noted. :)

Comment: 1) set drawn=false, then set to true if !0 is encountered 
2) detach the data from the image : var imgData = d.data but better : 3) the cherry : use a Int32Array to test the 4 component in one shot : 
var arr32 =  new Int32Array(d.data.buffer); 
len = arr32.length; You'll be more than 4 times faster. ( while ((i< len) && !arr32[i++]) {} ;
  drawn = (i != len); is the compact code for this :-) )

Answer (score 2):

Here a tips from Phrogz : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4649358

```
function eventOnDraw( ctx, eventName ){
  var fireEvent = function(){
    var evt = document.createEvent("Events");
    evt.initEvent(eventName, true, true);
    ctx.canvas.dispatchEvent( evt );
  }
  var stroke = ctx.stroke;
  ctx.stroke = function(){
    stroke.call(this);
    fireEvent();
  };
  var fillRect = ctx.fillRect;
  ctx.fillRect = function(x,y,w,h){
    fillRect.call(this,x,y,w,h);
    fireEvent();
  };
  var fill = ctx.fill;
  ctx.fill = function(){
    fill.call(this);
    fireEvent();
  };
}
...
var myContext = someCanvasElement.getContext('2d');
someCanvasElement.addEventListener( 'blargle', myHandler, false );
eventOnDraw( myContext, 'blargle' );
```

Answer (score 2):

Hey might be a late answer for this but I was kind of horrified to have the need of an extra canvas for comparing. So here is my solution:

```
if (canvas.toJSON().objects.length === 0) {
    console.log('canvas is empty');
}
```

I hope this helps, you can do a function with it but the solution is way cleaner than what I have seen around.

Comment: canvas.toJSON() function doesn't exist

Comment: `toJSON` is coming from a framework you are using or something ?

Answer (score 2):

HTML Code:

```
<canvas id='mainCanvas' style='border:solid'></canvas>
<canvas id='blankCanvas' style='display:none'></canvas>
```

JS Code:

```
var mainCanvas= new SignaturePad(document.getElementById("mainCanvas"));
if (mainCanvas.toDataURL() == document.getElementById('blankCanvas').toDataURL()) {
                // Canvas is blank
}
```

*Note: If your provide height and width to main canvas then same height and width to apply on blank canvas also.*

Comment: This saved me lots of time. It turns out that the .toDataURL() function does not return the same for a blank canvas in a PC vs a Mobile browser for example. I was comparing a hardcoded  "data:image/..." blob of an empty canvas on a PC  with the actual canvas .toDataURL(), but then on a mobile (phone) it would not behave correctly as in the PC. Creating a hidden canvas and comparing it with the canvas being displayed did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To get the pixels of the canvas you have to use the getImageData(); method -> [getImageData() reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_getimagedata.asp)

And to check if every pixels of your imageData are at 0 or 255.

Your ImageData will have 4 cells per pixels, r g b a and you cn access every pixels by incrementing your count by 4 and looking each 4 next numbers to hve your rgba value.

You can also get an empty image's DataURL and compare your canvas's DataURL to it to see if it's empty ;)

Answer (score 1):

I know it might be a late answer but try this solution:

Simon Sarris says that:

> Instead of checking every single pixel, it may be much more efficient to merely record every time the canvas gets filled or stroked.

While that would be more efficient, however I did manage to find a way to detect the canvas to see if it is drawn/painted on by checking every pixel. I had a play around to see what results does the pixel data returns when the canvas is empty and when it is been painted on. I found out that when the canvas is empty all of the pixel data returns `0` in all index positions of the array. So I used that to detect if there is any `0`'s or not and as the result I made it so it returns a boolean. If the canvas has been drawn on then it returns `true` and if it hasn't then it returns `false`.

You can test it [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Hazmatron/uvrw0d89/) on JSfiddle

code:

```
function isDrawnOn() {
            var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            var data = imageData.data;
            var result = null;
            var counter = 0;
            var last = data.length - 1;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (i === last && counter !== 0 && counter === last) {
                    result = false;
                    break;
                } else if (data[i] !== 0 && data[i] > 0) {
                    result = true;
                    break;
                } else {
                    counter++;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: what about if the same color data was drawn onto the same color background..