# How to evaluate onclick function on a canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

So, be this code, drawing a line in canvas:

```
var x = document.getElementById("canvas").onclick = function() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.moveTo(0, 0);
context.lineTo(300, 150);
context.stroke();
}
```

I want, for example to alert if the line was drawn. How can I do that? I mean something like `if(x===true) alert("aa");` I know it doesn't works in js.

Comment: Put your path commands (moveTo,lineTo,stroke) in a function. Have that function raise an alert (or set a flag) after drawing the line for you. BTW, A line is a path command and path commands should start with `context.beginPath` to avoid undesired redrawing. :-)

Comment: Did you resolve this question? If not, please provide more details. If yes, in order to close the question please either (a) choose a correct answer *by clicking checkmark beside answer*, or (b) write your own answer telling how you solved it (and mark that answer as the correct answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `change()` event for `<canvas>`, so you cannot attach an event handler to the canvas element as you would to a `div` or to an `input` element.

However, this question has some other ideas:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4649358

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("canvas").onclick = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.moveTo(0, 0);
    context.lineTo(300, 150);
    context.stroke();
    alert("aa"); /* here */
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10925934)

Comment: @GajusKuizinas what?

Comment: @GajusKuizinas. It does answer the question. This code-only answer would be more friendly with a label like "Add an alert after you stroke the line". Also, the questioner will need to change their design in order to make a useful app, but this post does correctly answer the question as asked. @CodeiSir: You should let the questioner know that path commands usually begin with `context.beginPath` so they don't do inadvertent redraws when path commands become inadvertently combined.

Comment: @markE your are totaly right. To be honest I think the question is realy strange, and I could not quite see what the guy does not understand. I hoped he would anwer this post in case it works or does not work for him.

Comment: "This does not provide an answer to the question." is misleading. The review form (the form used to review answers) is missing an option "Answer is a code block without an explanation." Providing just a code block is not considered a good answer.

Comment: @GajusKuizinas there is a comment in the code block providing all I know about this question. It's not my fault that the question is not well formulated. I can't answer better than that