# How to best tie into a webapp's mapbox-gl update code?

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, scala.js, browser-extension

## Background

I'm writing a browser extension which paints over the map of [komoot.com/plan](http://komoot.com/plan).
Currently I do this by placing a `canvas` on top of the existing `canvas`.

This works well but it is static and does not yet react to when the user moves the map around or zooms into it or the website focusses a particular location on the map.

## Question

How do I best tie into this event loop of map updates?

## Approaches considered

1. I could mimic / reimplement how komoot processes user input, but this sounds fragile and unreliable and messy. I would do this by adding listeners for mouse button events and cursor movement, etc.
2. The page's URL contains the lat and long coordinates together with the zoom level, e.g., `https://www.komoot.com/plan/@49.9535480,5.3956956,11.345z`. It changes **after** the map has changed. I assume there's a way to be notified of changes in the URL. If so I could then dynamically update my `canvas`.

   - This would still require some level of imitation of the page's internals. However, considerably less so than option 1.
   - Doing so I could only update my canvas after the animation is finished. Not a deal breaker but ideally I'd want to update it frame by frame together with the map itself for a more pleasing user experience.

## Additional Details

- Komoot seems to be using [mapbox-gl](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mapbox_GL)
- It's a [Manifest 2 Content Script](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/content_scripts/) extension
- This is my first browser extension ever
- I'm writing this in [Scala.js](https://www.scala-js.org) using [this excellent template](https://github.com/AlexITC/chrome-scalajs-template)

  - Don't let this keep you from posting javascript solutions or pointing me to javascript documentation!

## Screenshot

[image: Screenshot of Extension]

Comment: I guess you have to get when the map is changed then update your overlay.
there is a good explanation on how to catch canvas changes here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4649358/4146854
you can use the komoot canvas context and call your overlay change function based on komoot changes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have mentioned the obvious way: use the `move` event:

```
map.on('move',e => {...
   // get center with map.getCenter()
});
```

But it's not really clear exactly what you're trying to do, so hard to advise more specifically.

Comment: Exactly! What `map`? how do I access it? How do I find it within the minified JS the page is using? What fancy reverse engineering tools do JS people use nowadays? I got the `<canvas>` and the `<div>` its contained in together with respective class names, would I download all the JS sources used on the page by hand and just do a full text search for `new mapboxgl.Map` and hope I find something mentioning the class name and hope I can somehow access that JS object?
Obviously just entering `map` in the Chrome developer tools console gets me nowhere, that's not defined. So: How do I find it?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you had access to the map instance. If you don't, you're in serious trouble.