# Canvas file size (not dimensions)

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, base64

I have two canvas elements on my app, and on a certain point I want to compare their weight. I do this in order to determine if one of the canvas is empty (there's no picture drawn on it) or not.

I'm doing it like this:

```
if((canvas1.toDataURL()).length<(canvas2.toDataURL()).length){
    //empty canvas
}
```

That is, I'm comparing both canvas' base64 size.

This is, however, quite heavy.

Is there a lighter, more elegant way of doing this? Either determining if a canvas does not have an image drawn on it or comparing two canvas' weight.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476074/how-to-detect-if-html5-canvas-is-blank and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644524/how-to-check-if-something-is-drawn-on-canvas

Comment: From the second question, I got the "check pixel by pixel" method. Not quite sure if it's better performance wise than my solution, but it works.