# Canvas get percent of filled area

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I've got a canvas where the user can draw, but I need to detect the percent of filled area. The user has to continue to draw during the checking.

I already have my canvas and the user can draw on it. I got here a little function to check if some pixels aren't blank, but it's too slow and the user can't draw anymore.

Have you any idea of how I can do this?

UPDATE :

for drawing on my canvas I'm using `lineTo()` :

`$.fn.drawMouse = function() {
    var clicked = 0;
    var start = function(e) {
        clicked = 1;
        ctx.beginPath();
        x = e.pageX;
        y = e.pageY;
        ctx.moveTo(x,y);
    };
    var move = function(e) {
        if(clicked){
            x = e.pageX;
            y = e.pageY;
            ctx.lineTo(x,y);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    };
    var stop = function(e) {
        clicked = 0;
    };
    $(this).on("mousedown", start);
    $(this).on("mousemove", move);
    $(window).on("mouseup", stop);
};`

Comment: Hey, any luck on this one? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better, if you added a "x percent covered" value to a percentFilled variable each time the user draws something? 
Example:
Suppose you draw by creating circles. You can calculate the area of the circle, then perhaps check, if some of the pixels aren't already filled. Add (areaOfCircle (in %, or maybe px^2) - areaAlreadyFilled (in %, or maybe px^2) ) to your percentFilled variable and you get the current filled percentage. Everytime you paint something, it adds the painted area. You can completely avoid calculating the covered part of the canvas as a whole entirely.

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer, I updated my question.I'm using `lineTo()` for drawing in my canvas

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using for checking if the pixels aren't blank? Is it a function that moves through all pixels and checks if they are filled? How often do you fire it?

Comment: I take the code from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644524/how-to-check-if-something-is-drawn-on-canvas

Comment: Well if you are comparing a partially filled canvas to an empty one using toDataURL(), or using getImageData() I suppose you are testing the _entire_ canvas? Try only a section of it, after you finish adding the line. You can get which section you test by getting the rectangle of which the line is the diagonal or perhaps something more efficient but I hope you get the point.